# rlang: Input should be both a symbol and a string

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

So I need one of the arguments to be a symbol and the usual `!!enquo(column)` works, but I also need to make a `dplyr` join latter in the code using the same `column`.

Is there a problem with this? The code works I just want to know if it is correct.

```
f <- function(hello){ 
  hello <- enquo(hello)
## something using !!hello
  as_string(ensym(hello)) # here I need hello as a string
                          # because of by = hello in inner_join
}

f(hej)
```

Comment: Can you try to make this question reproducible?

Comment: Just take `ensym()` at the start, and use that throughout. `enquo()` is for complex expressions, but if you're using `ensym()` later on then you're abandoning support for complex expressions. Also using `ensym()` late means you'll get a late failure if the input is not a simple name.